# Theorem-like environments in Latexit?

Tags: theorems

I want to use Theorem-like environments in Latexit.

How can I do this?

Comment: According to the main page for LaTeXiT, "The interface is designed for equations, not for multi-pages documents. For such an usage, other applications my be more relevant.".  Since theorem-like stuff is (usually) outside the equation mode, the most likely answer is "You can't (at least, not without considerable hackery, such as embedding everything in `\text{...}`)".  However, this is more to do with the way LaTeXiT has been set up than with TeX so you'd probably be better off emailing/contacting LaTeXiT's support rather than asking here.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I do non-equation stuff in LaTeXiT all the time, including most of the images I put in answers here. The tool is designed to work with equations, but has a handy `text` button to work in text mode. Topologieeeee, can you put a MWE of a document with a simple example of what you'd like to achieve in LaTeXiT, and I'll see about some instructions for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this image:

[image]

- I have pulled down the little hidden panel for the preamble, and added the `amsthm` package. I have also added a definition for an *unnumbered* theorem environment.
- In the main box I've placed a little example.
- At the bottom, I have selected the **text** button, so that we are not in a mathematics environment.

As usual, you may now drag and drop the typeset snippet where you like. If you want to use the proof environment too, you may want to tell that environment not to use a Q.E.D. symbol, as this will appear way over to the right. To do that add

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
```

to the preamble.

[image]

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy TeXing!